# How to Perform a Full-Outer Join on Two Separate, Filtered Tables using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an original table named `Error`, and two additional tables (`ErrorBefore` and `ErrorAfter`) derived from the original (e.g. `ErrorAfter = ALLSELECTED('Error')`). I want to compare values from a 'before' version with an 'after' version, with the different version picked by slicer with 'Single select' on. That's working okay. Now I want to perform a full-outer join on the two results, joining on the `Message` column. The image below shows the result I have so far, with a fabricated table at the bottom of what I'm trying to achieve. I've tried using `NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN` and `GENERATE` but they either don't give the result that I seek. Does anyone know how to perform the join?

PBIX share [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjE2y1GgwOoMrJBwQqw3zSm0KiNa_Q).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change your data model to this:

[image]

I removed all your derived tables and relations, and instead created 2 tables like this:

```
Version Before = DISTINCT('Error'[Version])

Version After = DISTINCT('Error'[Version])
```

Both tables should have no relations with the Error table.

Then, create a measure:

```
Message Count = COUNT('Error'[Message])
```

You should always create measures yourself, never use Power BI auto-aggregations.

Next, create a measure for "Before" count"

```
Message Count Before = 
  VAR Version_Before = SELECTEDVALUE('Version Before'[Version])
RETURN
  CALCULATE([Message Count], 'Error'[Version] = Version_Before)
```

and, similarly:

```
Message Count After = 
  VAR Version_After = SELECTEDVALUE('Version After'[Version])
RETURN
  CALCULATE([Message Count], 'Error'[Version] = Version_After)
```

Finally, adjust your visuals:

- Slicer "Before" should be based on table "Version Before"
- Slicer "After" should be based on table "Version After"
- Charts and tables should use "Message Count Before" and "Message Count After" measures in values
- Add another table with messages and both measures

Result:

[image]